# HTMLをコメントアウトをしても、その中に書いてあるPHP処理はコメントアウトされない、というのは何の仕様でどこに書いてありますか？

Tags: php, html

HTMLをコメントアウトをしても、その中に書いてあるPHP処理はコメントアウトされない、ということを今知ったのですが、これは何の仕様(HTML? PHP?)でどこに書いてありますか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PHPタグ](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)でこう説明されています。

> PHP はファイルを解析して開始タグと終了タグ (`<?php`と`?>`) を探します。 タグが見つかると、PHP はコードの実行を開始したり終了したりします。 このような仕組みにより、PHP を他のあらゆる形式のドキュメント中に 埋め込むことができるのです。つまり、**開始タグと終了タグで囲まれている 箇所以外のすべての部分は、PHP パーサに無視されます。**

つまり、PHPタグの外側に何が書かれているか、PHP言語は関与していません。HTMLである必要もありません。

Answer (score 2):

PHP と HTML では解釈されるタイミング、実行場所が違います。

HTML に埋め込まれた PHP であっても、実行されるのはあくまでサーバサイドです。
(JavaScript のようにブラウザ上でソースを確認しても PHP のソースは表示されません)
PHP はサーバサイドで実行され、その結果を HTML に埋め込みます。

HTML のコメントアウトは PHP の外側ですから、PHP では解釈されません。